# using colon to specify two nouns

Tags: punctuation, colons

I want to say in contrast, X expression is elevated in only pancreas tissue and Y expression is elevated in only pituitary tissue. Can I write something like this?

> In contrast, X and Y expression elevated in only in one tissue: pancreas, pituitary.

Comment: That last sentence is not clear at all.  Only what you said at the beginning is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a colon to present the two types of tissue. To make the association clear, you should add "respectively":

> In contrast, X and Y expression increased in only one tissue [in each case]: pancreas and pituitary, respectively.

Note that I deleted an instance of "in" and changed the phrase to "expression increased," which is a much more common expression in the literature.

The addition of "in each case" further clarifies your meaning, as would a preceding sentence that reads something like "Expression of A, B, and C increased in both E and G."

You could also use, for example,

> A, B, and C expression was elevated in multiple tissue types. In contrast, X and Y expression increased only in the pancreas and in the pituitary, respectively.

or

> Expression of A, B, and C increased in both pancreas and pituitary tissue. In contrast, X expression increased only in the pancreas, and Y expression only in the pituitary.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to shorten the sentence by adding a colon. But it seems in your first example it is still long and complicated. I think your second example is very clear though it has no colon.

Comment: Can it (2nd example) be shortened like this? -  In contrast, X and Y expression increased only in the pancreas and pituitary, respectively.

Comment: Absolutely; this would be perfectly clear and succinct.